# Redshift Connection through SQL workbench,

Tags: amazon-redshift, sql-workbench-j

getting  error

`redshift failed to load driver class. this error may be caused by all-in-one jar packaging. please try again with the lean package`

Comment: Which JDBC driver are you using? Where did you download it from?

Comment: RedshiftJDBC4-1.2.1.1001, FROM AMAZON CONSOLE

Comment: Hope this helps: https://blog.openbridge.com/definitive-guide-for-connecting-sql-workbench-j-to-amazon-redshift-57d06aa32805

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same issue and the root cause ended up being because the path to the driver file consisted of a folder name that contained a space.

Comment: I checked , path doesn't have any spaces or special character......

Comment: I was facing the same issue. Placing the driver on a different directory (without spaces anywhere in the path) worked for me as well..!!

Comment: As weird as it sounds, removing spaces from the driver directory fixed my problem too. thanks bud.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with another program. As workaround try to use com.amazon.redshift.core.jdbc4.PGJDBC4DriverImpl as driver class name. It worked for me using RedshiftJDBC4-no-awssdk-1.2.8.1005.jar

Comment: In my case the reason of the problem is that when you call to connect method of Driver class this methods calls to getInstance and this method throws the exception because s_driver is null. The reason is that in the static code block the initialization failed. Maybe in the standard output you can see something more (exceptions are logged as System.err.println).

Answer (score 1):

There area number of drivers for Redshift. It seems like you are using an older version. I advise you review the documentation at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection.html

For example, here is the latest driver version.

JDBC 4.2–compatible driver: https://s3.amazonaws.com/redshift-downloads/drivers/RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.8.1005.jar.

Yours seems to be a few point releases older

Comment: I tried with latest driver , still getting same error